# Load via Jquery the head of a HTML to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying via Jquery to add the head section of an HTML file to multiple pages. I want to not need to repeat the tags in the head for every page I have to save time. 
To be cleare I want this part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

To be modular so I can include that on every HTML page.
I was trying to use the `load()` method but I got no idea how to make it load my head partial into the HTML.

I need to see an example of a solution for my issue as will help me to not waste time copying and paste the head everywhere.

Added the following workaround of what I need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $( "head" ).load( "./pages/partials/_head.html" );
    console.log("Loading...");

    var headMeta = `
    <title>NetFlix - Load </title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- FontAwesome 5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css">`;

    $("head").append(headMeta);
});
```

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a *"single page app (SPA)"*

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to include this directly on the server. For example, if you're using php, you could simply use [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Let's assume the following:

```
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
partials/header.html
```

In the `partials/header.html` file you'd simply place your content from above. In all the other files, you'd use

```
<?php include('partials/header.html') ?>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The reason to do this on the server, is that a browser will first "complete" you html, if it's missing sections, i.e. in this case it will add the `<head>` tag already.

You should be able to find a function similar to include for all languages.

---

Edit: if you are only allowed to use Javascript in the frontend, I think it would be easiest, to just copy the header. Another option would be to simply use a placeholder like `%HEADER%` and have a small script (i.e. python), that reads all `.html` files and replaces `%HEADER%` with the content and then saves the html file.
If that's also not what you're looking for, I would try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>$(function() { $.get('partials/header.html', function(content) {$('head').html(content);}); });</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm doing an exercise where PHP is not allowed and I actually know this solution but cannot be used. I need a solution whatever easy it is to append to my HTML the head and the scripts also if it will be not a best practice solution as I got to do JQ exercises like that.

Comment: Are you only allowed to use javascript in the frontend?

Comment: Yes I have Jquery exercises and I have to append to head the actual head with all the meat and links and do the same to more than 1 page

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Almost everything you have there is either:

- Not an element so can't be inserted into the DOM
- A mandatory element with optional start/end tags which will be in the DOM already so can't be inserted again
- An element that has no effect on browsers unless it is in the original HTML of the document (i.e. browsers pay attention when generating the original DOM, but changing or adding it afterwards with JavaScript has no effect)

You need to provide that data before the original HTML document is delivered to the browser.

If you want to automate this, then you can use a templating or include system in a server-side script or in a build script. You cannot usefully do this with client-side JavaScript (with or without the assistance of jQuery).